# How to implement functions that do the same with various fields of a struct?

Tags: c, oop, struct

I have the following struct:

```
struct tmatrix {
    struct tmatrix_entry {
        double price;
        double amt;
    } **entries;

    double *stocks;
    double *needs;
    int rows;
    int cols;
};
```

and the following functions:

```
void tmatrix_set_prices (struct tmatrix *tm, double *prices[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tm->rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < tm->cols; ++j)
            tm->entries[i][j].price = (prices) ? prices[i][j] : 0;
}

void tmatrix_set_amts (struct tmatrix *tm, double *amts[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tm->rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < tm->cols; ++j)
            tm->entries[i][j].amt = (amts) ? amts[i][j] : 0;
}
```

I guess it's not cool to make 2 almost identical functions, so I've so far come to this:

```
#define TMATRIX_SET_2D_ARRAY(TM, FIELD, ARRAY)\
do {\
    for (int i = 0; i < TM->rows; ++i)\
        for (int j = 0; j < TM->cols; ++j)\
            TM->entries[i][j].FIELD = (ARRAY) ? ARRAY[i][j] : 0;\
} while (0)
```

And then:

```
void tmatrix_set_prices (struct tmatrix *tm, double *prices[]) {
    TMATRIX_SET_2D_ARRAY(tm, price, prices);
}

void tmatrix_set_amts (struct tmatrix *tm, double *amts[]) {
    TMATRIX_SET_2D_ARRAY(tm, amt, amts);
}
```

Is this a bad solution? I've been told so. I've also been told that it could be done with offsetof(), but it looked more complex and harder to use. Or maybe it would have been better to make `entries` an array instead of structure? What's the best way to implement such functions?

Comment: This is really going to be a coding-style-preference question. There are lots of ways you can solve this without using a macro, but the macro definitely does do its job. This might be better suited to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You are saying that *...it's not cool to make 2 almost identical functions* but with your solution you still have the same  functions. An improvement whould be to have one function do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but how about using `offsetof()` along these lines:

```
#include <stddef.h>

static void tmatrix_set_field(struct tmatrix *tm, double *vals[],
                              const size_t f_offset) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tm->rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < tm->cols; ++j)
            *(double *)(((char *)&tm->entries[i][j]) + f_offset) =
                 (vals) ? vals[i][j] : 0;
}

void tmatrix_set_prices (struct tmatrix *tm, double *prices[]) {
    tmatrix_set_field(tm, prices, offsetof(struct tmatrix_entry, price));
}

void tmatrix_set_amts (struct tmatrix *tm, double *amts[]) {
    tmatrix_set_field(tm, amts, offsetof(struct tmatrix_entry, amt));
}
```

You mention that it "looked more complex", but seems potentially less complex than a macro.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce some of the redundant logic by using functions that set one entry of a `struct tm`. You can use those functions in the higher level functions.

```
typedef void (*set_matrix_data_function)(struct tmatrix *tm, double *data[], int i, int j);

void set_matrix_price(struct tmatrix *tm, double *data[], int i, int j)
{
   tm->entries[i][j].price = (data) ? data[i][j] : 0;
}

void set_matrix_amt(struct tmatrix *tm, double *data[], int i, int j)
{
   tm->entries[i][j].amt = (data) ? data[i][j] : 0;
}

void tmatrix_set_data (struct tmatrix *tm, double *data[], set_matrix_data_function fun)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tm->rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < tm->cols; ++j)
           fun(tm, prices, i, j);
}

void tmatrix_set_prices (struct tmatrix *tm, double *prices[])
{
   tmatrix_set_data(tm, prices, set_matrix_price);
}

void tmatrix_set_amts (struct tmatrix *tm, double *amts[])
{
   tmatrix_set_data(tm, prices, set_matrix_amt);
}
```

Notice that the code is more voluminous than having just two functions. This will pay off only if you  need more data members to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on the interface you present to the users of that struct rather than fixating on how it is implemented internally. With the two functions made available to users of the struct, you can switch back and forth between making those function bodies invocations of a macro being passed the name of the field or invocations of a function being passed the offset to that field with no rippling effects through your codebase. I agree that it is just a style preference.